# How to use image material together with shader?

Tags: texturing, shaders, uv-image-editor

Helo! I'm beginner in blender, i have a character with a cartoon stroke style shader and I would like to know **how to use an image with it**, I've already tried to insert an image with uv mapping, but the image doesn't stay in the original color.

---

---

[image]

[image]

---

Edit:

---

Thank you so much for everyone's attention, but I'm still having difficulties in making the effect, I'm still hopeful, because blender is a very powerful tool.

:)

The effect I would like to give would be something like the image below, but with the print in blue color and keeping the original effect of the cartoon shader.

[image]

Effect I would like to give the cartoon shader:

[image]

In case anyone wants to take a look, I'm uploading the file with the shader:

Blender - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SsUADODe6tabJGm8fvXH33LNaNMzKdgU/view?usp=sharing

Image - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xiWWsyzB_U273bxz0kdDPKrJgq4LPuLo/view?usp=sharing

Thank you all for your attention! :)

Comment: hello, "how to use an image with it" is too vague, maybe tell a little bit more precisely how you want your image to be displayed or to merge with the rest..

Comment: You pass your image texture to Principled BSDF shader, then convert the shader to color, then pass the color to 2 colors ramps - at this point you completely lose hue information, which is the most significant part responsible for losing color. If you select the bottom most color ramp and press **M** key to mute it, you probably will see the color.

Comment: @moonboots Hi, I'm not sure how to explain it because, as I said, I'm still a beginner in blender and I don't know the terms, but basically, I'd like to use the blue circle texture as in the image: (https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/4e3ccaa3-4c2c-44d3-96a2-6345f9c7d11a.3af3b5fb57c023e19c273790bb422a05.jpeg)
Thanks for listening :)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady  I tested it here, in fact, when hiding the last color ramp, it shows the color, but it loses the shader properties (the last color ramp is precisely the one responsible for giving the "cartoon effect"). Do you know any other possible configuration? Is there any way to use two materials at the same time in the blender?

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Terminology: A texture is any kind of information with dimension to it, such as an image, or a checkerboard generating formula (formula textures are called Procedural Textures). UV mapping controls where a texture is mapped onto the mesh. An incorrect UV map on a chip bag might result in the image being sideways or stretched. Shaders are “one or more” components of materials, and are instructions for how light reacts with a surface. Picking the wrong shader for a chip bag material might not affect the picture on the bag, but it might make the bag look like glass instead of glossy plastic.

Comment: I think instead of repairing your node setup (you could try something like this: https://i.imgur.com/5ZSUV7a.gif ) it's better to ask what you want to achieve exactly and we can help with that.

Comment: @NatCorsi, I've edited my answer, is it closer to what you want?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to put your blue pattern over the b&w lines, you can use this kind of setup (below). If you need to erase some parts of the pattern, you can do it in the 3D view and in *Texture Paint* mode use an *Draw brush > Blend > Erase Alpha*:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I tried to do it here, but it still has no colors, as it keeps going through the color ramp before going out to the material, the problem is that this color ramp is just the most important for the effect.

Thank you very much for your attention! :)

Comment: what you're trying to achieve is not clear enough, maybe show a picture of the effect you're trying to achieve

Comment: I just posted here, in case you need more information, you can let me know :) sorry if you have any English errors, it's not my default language.

Comment: It's closer yes, but I still haven't been able to adapt to the current shader settings, the problem is that there are 3 color ramps, and the mix only has 3 spaces, I tried to add one more mix, but it still didn't give the desired result of shading, I've moved all the way, but none of the colors appear.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/131sN3LqqzmGouAeoe-4W0Na0sbaVltWi/view?usp=sharing

This way I left it, it even turns blue, but the design only appears in the dark shade, which is not what I wanted.

Thanks for your attention and patience ^~^